# Unlisting a list in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe below. What I'd like to do is "unpack" the `PREV_AMT` column so that for each unique `id` in `BUS_ID`, the elements of the corresponding list in `PREV_AMT` become the values of the column (so that `PREV_AMT` has the same format as `AMT`).

The dataframe below is a result of the following function, so maybe I need to modify my function, but I don't know how.

```
def shift_amount(id, df):
    try:
        prev_amt = df[(df.BUS_ID == id)]["AMT"]
        prev_amt_shift = prev_amt.shift(1)
        prev_amt_shift.iloc[0] = np.mean(prev_amt)
        return prev_amt_shift.tolist()
    except:
        return df[(df.BUS_ID == id)]["AMT"][0]

test_df["PREV_AMT"] = test_df["BUS_ID"].apply(lambda x: shift_amount(x, df=test_df))
```

test_df

```
`YR    MON   BUS_ID      AMT                      PREV_AMT
2014    12  124649894   3583.14     [19992.0, 3583.14, 15055.16, 37343.25..
2015    1   124649894   15055.16    [19992.0, 3583.14, 15055.16, 37343.25..
2015    2   124649894   37343.25    [19992.0, 3583.14, 15055.16, 37343.25..
2015    3   124649894   15424.22    [19992.0, 3583.14, 15055.16, 37343.25..
2015    4   124649894   45275.73    [19992.0, 3583.14, 15055.16, 37343.25..
2015    5   124649894   3270.50     [19992.0, 3583.14, 15055.16, 37343.25..
2014    11  127533481   86.48              [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
2014    12  127533481   5065.45            [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
2015    1   127533481   8299.76            [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
2015    2   127533481   8336.18            [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
2015    3   127533481   10723.15           [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
2015    4   127533481   13743.79           [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
2015    5   127533481   3744.39            [7142.74285714, 86.48, 5065.45..
`
```

Comment: Can't you assign each value that's passed to AMT, to PREV_AMT too? Like a = b ?

Comment: Not following what you mean. I want PREV_AMT to be a shift of AMT, but to respect BUS_ID boundaries.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.